# django allways outputs a model field to PostgreSQL "character varying(200)"

Tags: django, postgresql

I new to django and PostgreSQL and I have a model that needs a URL so I used a `URLField`, but one of the URLs that it tries to save is longer then 200 which causes a:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(200)
```

I tried changing the `max_legnth` to 255 or the `URLField` to `TextField` but it always translates to type character varying(200) on PostgreSQL.

How can i address this issue?

Don't know if it matters but i use south.

Comment: Did you create a schema migration and migrate your database after updating the model? Otherwise the tables will stay the same as when you first created them.

Comment: Its an initial install.

Comment: Sounds like you should report a bug to the Django folks about this. There's no sane reason to set a string length limit. PostgreSQL doesn't care (or perform any different) so they should just use `text` or unconstrained `varchar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Evan Porter noted, you need to create new schema migration and then migrate.

Run:

```
python manage.py schemamigration <APP_NAME> --auto
python manage.py migrate
```

It should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

you should use TextField if you don't care length limitation of URL, with URLValidator

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
field = models.TextField(validators=[URLValidator()])
```

This behave like url field with.
after doing this you have to migrate your model using south.

Comment: have you migrated after change?, if you unable to migrate, you can do this manually using postgres alter table.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the specific `value too long for type character varying(200)` occurs when I have a `__unicode__` method defined in my model that may print out something longer than 200 symbols and I try to manipulate an instance in the admin view.

My 'fix' was to replace this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s - %s - %s' % (self.photo.title, self.photo.desc, self.user.fb_name)
```

With this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    title = None
    desc = None
    if self.photo.title:
        title = self.photo.title[:50]
    if self.photo.description:
        desc = self.photo.description[:50]
    return u'%s - %s - %s' % (title, desc, self.user.fb_name)
```